# Placing List Index when using List in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, collections

I was using a Set but now due to a widget restriction, I need to use a list.a 
a sample of my mapping file using A SET and a List are as follows. Can someone help me to place the list index. I am getting some confusion.

```
**Attribute Mapping File using Set**
?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 5:25:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="h.Attribute" table="ATTRIBUTE">
        <id name="AttributeId" type="long">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="AttributeName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTENAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="Options" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" inverse="false"  cascade="all" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="h.AttributeOption" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



 **Category Mapping File using Set**
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 8:37:02 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="h.Category" table="CATEGORY">
        <id name="CategoryId" type="long">
            <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="CategoryName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CATEGORYNAME" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="h.Category">
            <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
        </many-to-one>

        <set name="SubCategory" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="h.Category" />
        </set>

        <set name="AllAttributes" table="ATTRIBUTE" inverse="false" lazy="true"  cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="h.Attribute" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Category Mapping File using list without the list index**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 17, 2010 2:10:50 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="h.Category" table="CATEGORY">
        <id name="CategoryId" type="long">
            <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="CategoryName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CATEGORYNAME" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="h.Category" fetch="join">
            <column name="PARENTCATEGORY" />
        </many-to-one>
        <list name="SubCategory" inverse="false" table="CATEGORY" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="h.Category" />
        </list>
        <list name="AllAttributes" inverse="false" table="ATTRIBUTE" lazy="true"  cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="h.Attribute" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Attribute Mapping File using list with not list index**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 17, 2010 2:10:50 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="h.Attribute" table="ATTRIBUTE">
        <id name="AttributeId" type="long">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="AttributeName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTENAME" />
        </property>
        <list name="Options" inverse="false" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" lazy="true" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            </key>
            <list-index></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="h.AttributeOption" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: One more thing, I am not using any index!

Comment: You have posted 3 questions for this mappings, did any answer helped you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [Hibernate Reference: 6.2.3. Indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed)

For Example:

```
    <list name="whatEver">
        <key column="whatEver_fk"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="WhatEver"/>
    </list>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Hibernate 3.3 reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) says "The index of an array or list is always of type **integer**...", and also "If your table does not have an index column, and you still wish to use **list** as the property type, you can map the property as a Hibernate `<bag>`."

A example of bag:

```
<bag name="options" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" order-by="column_name asc|desc" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="ATTRIBUTEID" />
    <one-to-many class="h.AttributeOption" />
</bag>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should give "index" property in POJO for which you are creating one-to-many relation

```
<list name="whatEver">
        <key column="whatEver_fk"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="WhatEver_Class"/>
    </list>
```

In above example , "WhatEver_Class" POJO should have a index property , and it's hbm file should have below property tag.

```
<property name="index" type="long" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="idx" />
        </property>
```